# JavaCv: how to convert IplImage toBufferedImage

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have to convert an IplImage to a BufferedImage... what should be a simple task is becoming very intricate for me. I'm using JavaCv 1.0 on Mac OSX (which links with OpenCV 3.0).

In the old JavaCV API there was the IplImage method #getBufferedImage, but I can't find it anymore in new 1.0 API. So I tried to convert IplImage to byte array and byte array to BufferedImage. I found this solution to perform such conversion:

```
IplImage inputImg = cvLoadImage(imgName); //imgName is a JPEG absolute path
byte[] imageData = IplImageToByteArray( inputImg); //defined below
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(bais); //Always return null
```

where IplImageToByteArray can be defined in one of the following ways:

```
public static byte[] IplImageToByteArray(IplImage src) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = src.getByteBuffer();
    byte[] barray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(barray);
    return barray;
}

public static byte[] IplImageToByteArray2(IplImage src) {
    byte[] barray = new byte[src.imageSize()];
    src.getByteBuffer().get(barray);
    return barray;
}
```

The returned byte array is the same in both cases, but ImageIO.read returns always null value. I've no idea about what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: I found it by myself. Probably the reason why ImageIO.read always returns null is that the bytes of IplImage have a format that BufferedImage can't read. It is different from the common used PNG, JPG, BMP, ecc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static BufferedImage IplImageToBufferedImage(IplImage src) {
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    Frame frame = grabberConverter.convert(src);
    return paintConverter.getBufferedImage(frame,1);
}
```

Comment: For those who do first create the IplImage from a Frame (e.g. after grabber.grap() ), it's possible to use the paintConverter to convert the Frame directly to the BufferedImage w/o needing the IplImage... Just use the last line of Igor's answer.

Answer (score -1):

use "org.bytedeco.javacv.Java2DFrameUtils", and you will know what I said.

Comment: You have to explain why your answer will work. You can't just say "Try this, it will work !!".