# Tesseract 3.02.02 Crash JRE

Tags: java, c++, c, linux

We are using Tess4J/Tesseract to perform OCR on a webapp. On Windows everything works fine but when deployed on a Linux machine(CentOS 6.8) the program crashes and automatically kill the Apache tomcat server.

We are read more than one file(different file) simultaneously.if we run the OCR it running approximately 1 minutes after it through fatal error. Can you please suggest how to resolve?

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7d5934ff90, pid=17649,
>   tid=140176377489152

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:

```
 C [libtesseract.so.3.0.2+0x22cf90] tesseract::HistogramRect(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int*)+0x70
```

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try `ulimit -c unlimited` before starting Java again

Comment: You're going to have a really hard time running this in a *nix environment.  The tesseract library for Java is actually a JNI, Java Native Interface.  This means that it is a C/C++ library that has system specific code wrapped in Java code to allow you to execute methods within Java.  You would have to find a Linux specific version of tesseract to use it on a Linux machine.  The last time I looked, however, I couldn't find a Linux implementation

Comment: I'm using Linux(CentOS) support version of tesseract https://pkgs.org/download/tesseract

Comment: I'm Using tesseract version- 3.02.02, leptonica-1.69
  libjpeg 6b : libpng 1.2.49 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.3.if any update the version it will the solve fatal error?

Comment: If you  are using `TessBaseAPISetRectangle` to extract text from certain area, maybe in some images this area is not inside the image region and then you are getting this error. That was the reason of this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by resizing the image to a fixed size (you could do a percentage resize I guess) in javacv before passing it to tess4j.

Example of my resize method.

```
public static IplImage resize(IplImage img_source){
        IplImage resized = IplImage.create(600, 480, img_source.depth(), img_source.nChannels());
        cvResize(img_source,resized);
        return resized;
    }
```

Then I do my tesseract extraction below:

```
public static String extract(BufferedImage bi, Rectangle r) throws CvHandler, IOException, TesseractException{
        ITesseract tess = new Tesseract();
        String tessPath = getTess();
        tess.setPageSegMode(1);
        tess.setLanguage("eng");
        tess.setDatapath(tessPath);
        tess.setOcrEngineMode(TessOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT);
        tess.setTessVariable("load_system_dawg", "false");
        tess.setTessVariable("load_freq_dawg", "false");
        tess.setTessVariable("tessedit_create_hocr", "0");
        tess.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

        String result = "";
        if (!r.getBounds().isEmpty()){
            try{
                result = tess.doOCR(bi, r);
            }catch(TesseractException e){
                throw new CvHandler(e.getMessage());
            }
        }else result = tess.doOCR(bi);

        return result;
    }
```

Helper method for converting IplImage to BufferedImage [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873704/javacv-how-to-convert-iplimage-tobufferedimage):

```
public static BufferedImage convertIplToBuffered(IplImage img){

        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
        Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
        Frame frame = grabberConverter.convert(img);
        BufferedImage img_result = paintConverter.getBufferedImage(frame,1);

        return img_result;
    }
```